# Mongo DB connection failure. caught exception while starting klov server

Tags: mongodb, docker, extentreports

below is my yml file

version: '2'
services:
klov:
image: anshooarora/klov:1.0.1
container_name: klov
environment:
- SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017
ports:
- 80:80

while running below exception caught

\klov>docker-compose up
Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI, try `docker compose up`

Recreating klov ... done
Attaching to klov
klov    |  _     _
klov    | | |__ | |  ___   _ _
klov    | | / / | | / . \ | | |
klov    | |*_\ |*| _**/ |**/
klov    |
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:29,201 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger: Starting KlovApplication v1.0.1.RELEASE on cc23302f5445 with PID 1 (/klov.jar started by root in /)
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:29,206 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:30,640 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate: Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:30,842 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate: Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 188ms. Found 10 MongoDB repository interfaces.
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:32,085 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer: Tomcat initialized with port(s): 80 (http)
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:32,109 INFO  [main] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:32,110 INFO  [main] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Starting service [Tomcat]
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:32,111 INFO  [main] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.34]
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:32,386 INFO  [main] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:32,387 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3057 ms
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:32,954 INFO  [main] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,055 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='608cde908bf5c847418cded7', description='null'}-localhost:27017] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
klov    | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
klov    |       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70)
klov    |       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128)
klov    |       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
klov    |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
klov    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
klov    |       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
klov    |       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
klov    |       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
klov    |       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
klov    |       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
klov    |       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
klov    |       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64)
klov    |       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79)
klov    |       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
klov    |       ... 3 common frames omitted
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,547 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,548 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> nodes -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,550 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'nodes -> nodes'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,553 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> nodes -> history -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,555 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'nodes -> history -> nodes'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,557 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'history -> history'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,560 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> history -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,561 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> history -> nodes -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,563 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'nodes -> nodes'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,564 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'history -> nodes -> history'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,566 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'history -> history'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,567 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,568 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'nodes -> parentTest -> nodes'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,570 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> history -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,571 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'nodes -> parentTest -> history -> nodes'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,573 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'history -> history'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,575 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'nodes -> nodes'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,578 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,579 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'nodes -> history -> parentTest -> nodes'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,581 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'history -> parentTest -> history'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,583 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'nodes -> history -> nodes'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,585 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'history -> history'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,587 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,588 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> nodes -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,590 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'nodes -> nodes'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,592 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'history -> parentTest -> nodes -> history'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,594 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'history -> parentTest -> history'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,596 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,598 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'nodes -> parentTest -> nodes'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,599 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'history -> nodes -> parentTest -> history'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,600 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'nodes -> nodes'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,602 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'history -> nodes -> history'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,603 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$1: Found cycle for field '_id' in type 'Test' for path 'history -> history'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,604 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver: Found cycle for field 'parentTest' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,606 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver: Found cycle for field 'parentTest' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> nodes -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,609 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver: Found cycle for field 'parentTest' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> history -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,610 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver: Found cycle for field 'parentTest' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,612 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver: Found cycle for field 'parentTest' in type 'Test' for path 'nodes -> nodes'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,614 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver: Found cycle for field 'nodes' in type 'Test' for path 'nodes -> nodes'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,617 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver: Found cycle for field 'parentTest' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,618 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver: Found cycle for field 'nodes' in type 'Test' for path 'nodes -> history -> nodes'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,620 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver: Found cycle for field 'parentTest' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,622 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver: Found cycle for field 'parentTest' in type 'Test' for path 'parentTest -> parentTest'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,623 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver: Found cycle for field 'nodes' in type 'Test' for path 'nodes -> nodes'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,625 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver: Found cycle for field 'parentTest' in type 'Test' for path 'history -> history'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,627 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver: Found cycle for field 'parentTest' in type 'Test' for path 'history -> history'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,629 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver: Found cycle for field 'nodes' in type 'Test' for path 'history -> history'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:33,631 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver: Found cycle for field 'history' in type 'Test' for path 'history -> history'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:35,568 INFO  [main] org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport: Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:35,859 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WelcomePageHandlerMapping: Adding welcome page template: index
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:36,675 INFO  [main] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:36,737 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer: Tomcat started on port(s): 80 (http) with context path ''
klov    | 2021-05-01 04:52:36,745 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger: Started KlovApplication in 8.603 seconds (JVM running for 9.703)
[image: Mongo DB connection as per the image started]

Comment: 'Connection refused' means the operating system actively rejected the connection because nothing is listening on that port.

Comment: I have updated yml file with SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017 working fine

version: '2'
services:
    klov:
        image: anshooarora/klov:1.0.1
        container_name: klov
        environment:
            - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017
        ports:
            - 80:80

Answer (score 0):

updated SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017 and it is working

version: '2'
services:
klov:
image: anshooarora/klov:1.0.1
container_name: klov
environment:
- SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017
ports:
- 80:80